# Minha resposta retorna undefined

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, for, express.js

Estou usando o node para desenvolver uma aplicação.

Estou fazendo uma consulta no banco para puxar uns valores. Esses valores são: **'imagem1', 'imagem2, 'imagem3'**.

Estou querendo utilizar um for para aplicar uma função nas 3 imagens:

```
const consulta = await conn.where({id: '10'}).select('*').table('cadastro')

    for (let i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
        console.log(`${consulta[0].imagem} ${i}`)
    }
```

A constante consulta me retorna o que quero, porém, o problema está na hora de printar.

Esse console:

```
console.log(`${consulta[0].imagem} ${i}`),
```

me retorna undefined1, undefined2, undefined3, ele não concatena.
Mas se eu fizer assim:

```
console.log(`${consulta[0].imagem1}`)
console.log(`${consulta[0].imagem2}`)
console.log(`${consulta[0].imagem3}`)
```

ocorre tudo corretamente, me trazendo os valores.

Não seria uma boa prática eu printar várias vezes, pois, se eu tiver 100 imagens, será um trabalho enorme. Eu preciso utilizar o for para isso, mas a concatenação não funciona, me retorna **'undefined'**

Alguém teria uma solução para me ajudar?

Comment: Qual o resultado de `console.log(consulta)`?

Comment: [
  RowDataPacket {
    id: 10,
    nome: 'Marianna da',
    sobrenome: 'Lemos',
    idade: 2,
    imagem1: 'iPhone-12-5.jpg1610543032642.jpg',
    imagem2: 'iphone12-concept12-scaled.jpg1610543032647.jpg',
    imagem3: 'TR_Iphone12_3D-1-2-920x613.png1610543032651.png'
  }
]

Comment: Ele me retorna os dados normalmente

Comment: Veja se é isto que você está tentando fazer: `console.log(consulta[0]['imagem' + i])`

Comment: Acho que o ideal aí seria colocar essas imagens em um vetor dentro do objeto, se for possível alterar o banco